# How to make Django Formset Management Forms Generate Unique IDs for Fields

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am making an 'Project' program where users can write articles with a variable number of images and associate a list of various important dates with their article.
According to the Django documentation, using formsets along with javascript can create dynamic forms for this purpose.

However, when trying to implement this for both my `image_formset` and my`date_formset` I opened the console to find that both the `{{ image_formset.management_form }}` and `{{ date_formset.management_form }}` had the same IDs for every field.

[image: image showing same IDs for each field in Django's formset management_form]

Because of this I cannot use javascript to update the `form-TOTAL_FORMS` fields to properly reflect how many forms are currently being used. Is there any way to fix so that each `form-TOTAL_FORMS` can be selected uniquely?

I may attempt to work around the problem by adding the parent of `{{ date_formset.management_form }}` to the script's criteria for selection, but I think having two html elements with the same ID is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out I just can't read documentation:

The solution is to initiate the formset with the parameter `prefix="unique-prefix-for-this-formset"` (So if there was a formset defined as `FormSet` it should initialize as `Formset(prefix='foo')` ). The result is that IDs such as `id-TOTAL_FORM` in the previous image becomes `id_image-TOTAL_FORM` and each management form can be accessed individually for changing.

The example of this in the documentation can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view

Hope this experience at least helps someone out :)